# SharePoint List Of Recently Updated Pages

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, alert

I am trying to find a way to inform a group of users whenever any of the pages in our SharePoint site are updated.

Originally we were going to use alerts, but we have numerous subsites in our site.  This means (to the best of my knowledge) that we will have to set up alerts for every subsite.  This is not an option because subsites will be created and removed and we would rather not add an extra step here.

Secondly, we wanted to use a Content Query webpart to simply show all pages that were updated in the last 5 days.  This would allow us to show every page for every site, but I can't figure out how to get it to only show items with an update date >= today's date - 5.

If anyone can help me out, I would really appreciate it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track with the Content Query Web Part. Unfortunately out of the box it forces you to set a specific date rather than a certain number of days.

Your best option is to override the Content Query Web Part or write your own that provides the functionality you require. There may also be other query web parts available that do this for you. If you write your own, the following CAML query should help:

```
<Where>
   <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name='Modified' />
      <Value Type='DateTime'>
         <Today OffsetDays='-5' />
      </Value>
   </Geq>
</Where>
```

Answer (score 2):

The What's New Web Part by Jan Tielens is good for this sort of thing, and it has a few configurable parameters, such as maximum age of items, scope (recursive etc) and the ability to filter by content types.

http://smarttools.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=What%27s%20New